# MPI Finalize taking forever

Tags: c, parallel-processing, mpi, openmpi

I noticed that in my MPI program MPI_Finalize() takes a long time to complete, in the order of 10/20 seconds, while the program itself completes in few milliseconds (it produces the correct results almost instantaneously).

The OPENMPI manual http://www.open-mpi.org/doc/v1.6/man3/MPI_Finalize.3.php states that MPI_Finalize() should only check for pending communications. I infer that it should either fail if some communication is not matched or complete very quickly.

What could be possible explanations for MPI_Finalize taking so much time to complete?

**update:** The problem seems to show up when executing the same program multiple times, i.e., the first execution of MPI_Finalize is generally fast and then it degrades.
It is evident even for very simple programs like this one:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <mpi.h>


    int main (int argc,char* argv[])
    {
    int rank, size;

    MPI_Init (&argc, &argv);      /* starts MPI */
    MPI_Comm_rank (MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);        /* get current process id */
    MPI_Comm_size (MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);        /* get number of processes */
    printf( "Hello world from process %d of %d\n", rank, size );
    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
    }
```

Moreover, the problem seems to be unaffected by the number of processes.
I am experiencing this problem on a dual socket Intel Xeon E5520  @ 2.27GHz.

**update 2**

```
[andromeda.di.unipi.it:03918] procdir: /tmp/openmpi-sessions lottarin@andromeda.di.unipi.it_0/18136/0/0
[andromeda.di.unipi.it:03918] jobdir: /tmp/openmpi-sessions-lottarin@andromeda.di.unipi.it_0/18136/0
[andromeda.di.unipi.it:03918] top: openmpi-sessions-lottarin@andromeda.di.unipi.it_0
[andromeda.di.unipi.it:03918] tmp: /tmp
[andromeda.di.unipi.it:03918] mpirun: reset PATH: /tmp/OPENMPI/bin:/usr/kerberos/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/home/lottarin/bin
[andromeda.di.unipi.it:03918] mpirun: reset LD_LIBRARY_PATH: /tmp/OPENMPI/lib
[andromeda.di.unipi.it:03918] [[18136,0],0] orted_cmd: received add_local_procs


MPIR_being_debugged = 0
  MPIR_debug_state = 1
  MPIR_partial_attach_ok = 1
  MPIR_i_am_starter = 0
  MPIR_forward_output = 0
  MPIR_proctable_size = 4
  MPIR_proctable:
    (i, host, exe, pid) = (0, andromeda.di.unipi.it, /home/lottarin/PROVE_MPI/./a.out, 3919)
    (i, host, exe, pid) = (1, andromeda.di.unipi.it, /home/lottarin/PROVE_MPI/./a.out, 3920)
    (i, host, exe, pid) = (2, andromeda.di.unipi.it, /home/lottarin/PROVE_MPI/./a.out, 3921)
    (i, host, exe, pid) = (3, andromeda.di.unipi.it, /home/lottarin/PROVE_MPI/./a.out, 3922)
MPIR_executable_path: NULL
MPIR_server_arguments: NULL
[andromeda.di.unipi.it:03920] procdir: /tmp/openmpi-sessions-lottarin@andromeda.di.unipi.it_0/18136/1/1
[andromeda.di.unipi.it:03920] jobdir: /tmp/openmpi-sessions-lottarin@andromeda.di.unipi.it_0/18136/1
[andromeda.di.unipi.it:03920] top: openmpi-sessions-lottarin@andromeda.di.unipi.it_0
[andromeda.di.unipi.it:03920] tmp: /tmp
[andromeda.di.unipi.it:03918] [[18136,0],0] orted_recv: received sync+nidmap from local proc [[18136,1],1]
[andromeda.di.unipi.it:03919] procdir: /tmp/openmpi-sessions-lottarin@andromeda.di.unipi.it_0/18136/1/0
[andromeda.di.unipi.it:03919] jobdir: /tmp/openmpi-sessions-lottarin@andromeda.di.unipi.it_0/18136/1
[andromeda.di.unipi.it:03919] top: openmpi-sessions-lottarin@andromeda.di.unipi.it_0
[andromeda.di.unipi.it:03919] tmp: /tmp
[andromeda.di.unipi.it:03918] [[18136,0],0] orted_recv: received sync+nidmap from local proc [[18136,1],0]
[andromeda.di.unipi.it:03920] [[18136,1],1] node[0].name andromeda daemon 0
[andromeda.di.unipi.it:03919] [[18136,1],0] node[0].name andromeda daemon 0
[andromeda.di.unipi.it:03922] procdir: /tmp/openmpi-sessions-lottarin@andromeda.di.unipi.it_0/18136/1/3
[andromeda.di.unipi.it:03922] jobdir: /tmp/openmpi-sessions-lottarin@andromeda.di.unipi.it_0/18136/1
[andromeda.di.unipi.it:03922] top: openmpi-sessions-lottarin@andromeda.di.unipi.it_0
[andromeda.di.unipi.it:03922] tmp: /tmp
[andromeda.di.unipi.it:03918] [[18136,0],0] orted_recv: received sync+nidmap from local proc [[18136,1],3]
[andromeda.di.unipi.it:03921] procdir: /tmp/openmpi-sessions-lottarin@andromeda.di.unipi.it_0/18136/1/2
[andromeda.di.unipi.it:03921] jobdir: /tmp/openmpi-sessions-lottarin@andromeda.di.unipi.it_0/18136/1
[andromeda.di.unipi.it:03921] top: openmpi-sessions-lottarin@andromeda.di.unipi.it_0
[andromeda.di.unipi.it:03921] tmp: /tmp
[andromeda.di.unipi.it:03918] [[18136,0],0] orted_recv: received sync+nidmap from local proc [[18136,1],2]
[andromeda.di.unipi.it:03922] [[18136,1],3] node[0].name andromeda daemon 0
[andromeda.di.unipi.it:03921] [[18136,1],2] node[0].name andromeda daemon 0
[andromeda.di.unipi.it:03918] [[18136,0],0] orted_cmd: received message_local_procs
[andromeda.di.unipi.it:03918] [[18136,0],0] orted_cmd: received message_local_procs
Hello world from process 1 of 4
Hello world from process 3 of 4
Hello world from process 0 of 4
Hello world from process 2 of 4
[andromeda.di.unipi.it:03918] [[18136,0],0] orted_cmd: received message_local_procs
[andromeda.di.unipi.it:03918] [[18136,0],0] orted_recv: received sync from local proc [[18136,1],1]
[andromeda.di.unipi.it:03918] [[18136,0],0] orted_recv: received sync from local proc [[18136,1],3]
[andromeda.di.unipi.it:03918] [[18136,0],0] orted_recv: received sync from local proc [[18136,1],0]
[andromeda.di.unipi.it:03920] sess_dir_finalize: proc session dir not empty - leaving
[andromeda.di.unipi.it:03922] sess_dir_finalize: proc session dir not empty - leaving
[andromeda.di.unipi.it:03918] [[18136,0],0] orted_recv: received sync from local proc [[18136,1],2]
[andromeda.di.unipi.it:03919] sess_dir_finalize: proc session dir not empty - leaving
[andromeda.di.unipi.it:03921] sess_dir_finalize: proc session dir not empty - leaving
**LAGS HERE after having received sync from all processes**
[andromeda.di.unipi.it:03918] [[18136,0],0] orted_cmd: received waitpid_fired cmd
[andromeda.di.unipi.it:03918] [[18136,0],0] orted_cmd: received iof_complete cmd
[andromeda.di.unipi.it:03918] sess_dir_finalize: proc session dir not empty - leaving
[andromeda.di.unipi.it:03918] [[18136,0],0] orted_cmd: received iof_complete cmd
[andromeda.di.unipi.it:03918] [[18136,0],0] orted_cmd: received waitpid_fired cmd
[andromeda.di.unipi.it:03918] sess_dir_finalize: proc session dir not empty - leaving
[andromeda.di.unipi.it:03918] [[18136,0],0] orted_cmd: received waitpid_fired cmd
[andromeda.di.unipi.it:03918] [[18136,0],0] orted_cmd: received iof_complete cmd
[andromeda.di.unipi.it:03918] [[18136,0],0] orted_cmd: received iof_complete cmd
[andromeda.di.unipi.it:03918] sess_dir_finalize: proc session dir not empty - leaving
[andromeda.di.unipi.it:03918] [[18136,0],0] orted_cmd: received waitpid_fired cmd
[andromeda.di.unipi.it:03918] sess_dir_finalize: proc session dir not empty - leaving
[andromeda.di.unipi.it:03918] sess_dir_finalize: job session dir not empty - leaving
[andromeda.di.unipi.it:03918] [[18136,0],0] Releasing job data for [18136,1]
[andromeda.di.unipi.it:03918] sess_dir_finalize: job session dir not empty - leaving
[andromeda.di.unipi.it:03918] [[18136,0],0] Releasing job data for [18136,0]
[andromeda.di.unipi.it:03918] sess_dir_finalize: proc session dir not empty - leaving
orterun: exiting with status 0
```

Comment: There are many possible explanations. How about you show us some code and give the question more context?

Comment: I added a simple program example and the machine that I am using, thanks for your help!

Comment: This doesn't really add much of a context. What Open MPI version do you use? Are you running on a single node or is it a cluster your are running at? If so, on how many nodes do you run the MPI job? What filesystem is used? Is it local or a shared network one? etc.

Comment: Open MPI 1.6 on a single multicore node. As i mentioned earlier changing the number of MPI processes does not help, even running a single process takes a unreasonable amount of time to complete. The OS is linux 2.6.32.59. fs is ext3.

Comment: Sounds like an OS issue - I've never seen such behaviour on a single node. Could you please provide the output from running `mpiexec --debug-daemons --debug-devel <other options as before>`?

Comment: This shouldn't be the case, but is /tmp on a network file system by chance?

Comment: I think you should ask your question on the Open MPI User [mailing list](http://www.open-mpi.org/community/lists/ompi.php). Jeff Squyres roams StackOverflow but he would be more inclined to help you on the mailing list.